# How to change the user entered text color in TextformField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change the color of the text when the user enters something. But when only if the user enter something. Otherwise, it should remain the same that is grey. For this, I am creating a Focus Node inside the component and assigning it to the textformfield `focusNode` property. In `initState` I am adding a listener so whenever my textformfield has focus I can change the color of the hint text as well as the border color. But it is giving me an error and I am not able the change the color of the user enter text.

```
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
 @override
 void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() => color = _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And my component is like this below :

```
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(30.0),
    ),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: textController,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      onTap: _requestFocus,
      keyboardType: this.widget.type,
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
      onChanged: (value) => {
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.blue;
        })
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        color: color,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontSize: 15.0,
      ),
      obscureText: widget.obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0xFFFCFCFC),
        hintText: this.widget.hintText,
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: _focusNode.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(50.0),
          ),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          this.widget.icon,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        return;
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

I am not able to determine what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I have move the initialization of the focus node in `initSate` and in `onChanged` property i am setting the color to grey within `setState`. but still giving error `Failed assertion: line 742 pos 12: 'attached': is not true.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing these changes :

```
void _requestFocus() {
   setState(() {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
            });
          }
```

removing onChanged call back and giving the color blue to the textfield.
Thats it.